# Problem with Modernizr -> ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined (Firefox console)

Tags: javascript

Have a problem with .js script which I'm trying to use in my webpage for geolocation. On Firefox console I have an error message:

> "ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined".

Here is the code of script:

```
var elMap = document.getElementById('loc');
var msg = 'Sorry, we where unable to get your location.';

if(Modernizr.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
    elMap.textContent = 'Checking location...';
}else{
    elMap.textContent = msg;
}

function success(position){
    msg = '<h3>Longitude:<br>';
    msg += position.coords.longitude + '</h3>';
    msg += '<h3>Latitude:<br>';
    msg += position.coords.latitude + '</h3>';
    elMap.innerHTML = msg;
}

function fail(msg){
    elMap.textContent = msg;
    console.log(msg.code);
}
```

The script is included on end of a body of webpage, right before `</body>` tag.

Comment: Where have you included Modernizr? Is it loaded?

Comment: :( now I see why ...
sry for bothering.